# Have VS Code execute a command line call when failing to save

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, events, thenable

My company uses Cliosoft for source control.  If I do not check out a file in Cliosoft, it will fail to save in VS Code since the file will only have read access.  I want to setup VS Code such that when it detects that a file failed to save, it runs a command line call (soscmd -co filename) and then tries to save again

I looked at the VS Code API, particularly onWillSaveTextDocument and onDidSaveTextDocument.  I imagine through the combination of those two events I could make something up but I am not very familiar with how events and thenables work in Javascript

Comment: Isn't it enough to react on `onWillSaveTextDocument` and then run `soscmd -co filename`?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the existing extensions that allow you to run code on save?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=run%20on%20save&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: @md2perpe Wouldn't reacting on onWillSaveTextDocument always run the command even if the save was successful?  That would not be ideal.  I will look at the extension you sent, thank you!

Comment: The command will be run before each attempt to save the document, even if the save will be successful.

Comment: But I only want it to run if the save was not successful

Comment: I understand that you want the following flow: try to save; if failed then checkout file and try to save again. But if you cannot get that flow, you should look at alternative solutions. What happens if you run 'checkout' on a file that is already checked out? Is there any way to check whether a file is checked out? Is that fast?